# strongloop id not storing as string

Tags: javascript, node.js, strongloop

I'm currently using strongloop to develop an application.  Although I have already specified my id to type string, when I store a record, it came out as a string of objects.

This is my model.json file

```
"id": {
  "type:": "string",
  "id": true
},
```

and the result in the psql database is

```
{"0":"P","1":"K","2":"U","3":"W","4":"7","5":"C","6":"E","7":"B"}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction of why this is the case?  I used a npm library to generate the string.

```
var shortid = require('shortid32');
var newID = shortid.generate();
```

Anyone knows what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Add below configuration to `id` :

```
"id": {
  "type:": "string",
  "id": true,
"postgresql": {
          "columnName": "id",
          "dataType": "character varying",
          "nullable": "NO"
        }
},
```